Knowledge Repository
The rule across the SE network is General Questions General Answers.
The sites are a repository of knowledge.
Mokubai said that it is not a place to collate encyclopedic information that Super User is a place for people to solve their problems (relating to computer use).
How does that work, is SuperUser.SE a repository of general knowledge or a place to get help on a specific problem?

I note you posted an almost identical question, complete with the same typos on Parenting.
So, we have a fairly comprehensive set of help pages which cover many of these issues, and quite a lot of it is identical across the network. We also tend to work well because our sites are generally narrowly scoped, and people can find the answers on the topics we need on a specific site (as opposed to say, the quora model, or the reddit model where they are sub communities on a single site).
I would recommend you ponder our don't ask page. I'd also consider that the end user might be more interested in the pitfalls and advantages of say, a particular display type over the design, fabrication or other details.

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

In an ideal world, we're a repository of solutions as opposed to 'explain things about a computer' site. While there's wiggleroom, we're certainly not designed to be used as an encyclopedia.
